# Adjusting bootstrap 12 grid in same row length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

good day, I have a goal of aligning all images and test in my 12 grid bootstrap column. i divided it in 6, 4, and 2 but the icons in the 2 column does not match the length with the other columns. i have images of the current one and the layout that i intended to create.

[image]
[image]

```
          <div class="container-full col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="display_img">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 class="text-center">A Wealth of Deals for Wellness</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="img/link_beauty.png">
                <img src="img/link_health.png">
                <img src="img/link_wellness.png">
                <img src="img/link_partners.png">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `class="img-responsive"` class to `<img>` tag for creating the images responsive. Please see the below updated code:

```
<div class="container-full col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="display_img img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <h1 class="text-center">A Wealth of Deals for Wellness</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <img src="img/link_beauty.png" class="img-responsive">
         <img src="img/link_health.png" class="img-responsive">
         <img src="img/link_wellness.png" class="img-responsive">
         <img src="img/link_partners.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my main concern is adjusting my icons on the right to the same size as the picture on the left

Comment: @Hadrian Clayton You need to add `max-width: 100px`(You can change as per your requirement) and `height: auto` to `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Hadrian Clayton add class to right side images which is inside the `class="col-md-2"` class. And add above properties in your css.